# Show that if $A$ is idempotent then $(AB-ABA)^2=0$ for all $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How can I prove that if $A$ is idempotent then $(AB-ABA)^2=0$ for all $B$.

Comment: You would have a better chance of getting a response that matches your level of understanding if the problem statement is put into context:  Why is this Question difficult or interesting for you?  What approach did you consider, given the worked examples/proofs or stated theorems that preceded this exercise?

Answer (score 5):

Multiply it out to get
$$ ABAB-ABABA-ABAAB+ABAABA$$
and replace all $AA$ with $A$. What happens?

Comment: One wonders what the OP tried… :-/